# Icon is not disappearing after removing the app

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I've jailbroken iPhone4s (iOS 7.1) with pangu. Through cydia I've installed Terminal app. Then I've uninstalled the app. But the icon on the screen is not going. Does that mean uninstallation was not successful? If so how can I remove that completely?

Steps taken to uninstall

- cydia -> installed(option) -> chose terminal -> modify (top right corner) -> chose remove

Comment: What steps precisely did you take to "uninstall the app"? Did you power cycle the device? Is a total wipe an option? (Just use the edit button to clarify things if the existing answer isn't what you seek)

Comment: please refer the edited question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `uicache` as mobile, then respring (`killall SpringBoard`).

Comment: I did uicache.. then how about respring?

Comment: @Venu `killall SpringBoard`

Comment: yep! But it is showing 'No matching process belonging to you were found'

Comment: @Venu SpringBoard is case sensitive.